# Header go small on scrolling

Tags: jquery

I want to make my header go small after scroll down `400px` down my page. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(top);
        /*put your color in background color */
        if (top > 400) {
            $('#header').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)');
            $('#header').css('height', '70px');
            $('#logo').css('height', '60px');
            $('#logo').css('width', '100px');
            $('#logo img').css('height', '60px');
            $('#logo img').css('width', '100px');
            $('#nav').css('height', '40px');
            $('#nav a').css('color', '#888');
            $('#nav a').css('font-size', '14px');
            $('#nav').css('position', 'relative');
            $('#nav').css('left', '40%');
        } else {
            $('#header').css('background-color', 'Transparent');
            $('#header').css('height', '130px');
            $('#logo').css('height', '100px');
            $('#logo').css('width', '200px');
            $('#logo img').css('height', '100px');
            $('#logo img').css('width', '200px');
            $('#nav').css('height', '70px');
            $('#nav a').css('color', '#000000');
            $('#nav a').css('font-size', '20px');
            $('#nav').css('position', 'relative');
            $('#nav').css('top', '-50px');
            $('#nav').css('left', '0');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Its not working. My logo, header size and menu need to become small too with the header.

Comment: CSS:    .header{
width: 100%;
height: 130px;
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 500;
}

Comment: <div id="header">
<div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" /></div>
<div id="nav">
<ul><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="brands.php">Our Brands</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="reachus.php">Reach Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Catalogue</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Id recommend adding a class-name to top level that overrides desired properties (and child properties) with css classes, quicker (though query pretty quick anyway) and use of "parent > child" will help remove reliance of id tags and potential issues if multiple navs used anywhere or such. Though multiple properties in single line do solve managability somewhat.

Comment: i need the complete code

Comment: @AayushGarg - please do update OP to include the html, css and other such parts - comments are not used for that. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask